# Python Contains TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, pentaho

I'm attempting to coerce a Python script to run from a Pentaho job. This is a windows machine, and I've managed to do most of the conversion so it will run without issues. I am having some problems with a couple of lines. One of them is this guy:

```py
if prop_path is None:
    prop_path = 'C:\\Properties\\Properties.xml' % shared_location
```

I am a .NET guy, so I am out of my element here and wondering what I am missing.

Thanks.

Comment: You need a `%` in the format string, which will be replaced with `shared_location`.

Comment: do you want to concadinate the string?

Comment: You shouldn't use string concatenation or formatting to create paths. Use `os.path.join()` or `pathlib`.

Comment: try this `prop_path = f'C:\\Properties\\Properties.xml' {shared_location}`